# iOS : How load remote CSS to my UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have some HTML strings and a remote CSS link.
I want to load the HTML strings and add the CSS to it in my webView.
How can I do it? Thanks!

```
[_webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:someurl];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either

1. fetch the CSS over the network (with e.g. [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) & friends)
2. load it with `loadHTMLString:` enclosed in `<style>[...]</style>` tags (e.g. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<style>%@</style>", loadedCSSString]`)

or

use Javascript (`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`) inside the webview, create and insert a `link` tag:

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
link.setAttribute('href', '<your remote CSS link>');
document.head.appendChild(link);
```

The HTML must of course already be loaded when you do this.